# Android simulate temporary Activity destruction?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is there a way to simulate an Activity being "temporarily" destroyed (as described in the [Activity.onDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) documentation)?

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, **or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space**. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

It appears this is happening to my App on some devices. After the "temporary" onDestroy, the Activity gets later gets an onResume, which isn't handled properly by my code (and, I would like to test and correct this).

Comment: Are you saying you see indications that `onDestroy()` is called for an activity, and then `onResume()` is called for the same activity?

Comment: That's what is being reported to me, yes.

Comment: I'd be very skeptical of those reports.  All the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) describing the Activity lifecycle indicates it will never happen.

Comment: I'm always skeptical when somebody tells me there's a bug in my code :).

Answer (score -1):

In Developer Options in the phone's settings, near the bottom of the list, you can turn on "Don't keep Activities". When you press the home button, the system will destroy your Activity sort-of mimicking a low-memory situation. When you re-open your application, your activity will be re-created with a savedInstanceState bundle.

To enable Developer Options, go to 'Settings -> About phone' and click on the Build number 7 times quickly.

**Edit:** if this doesn't reproduce your problem, you can also try force-closing your app from ddms and re-opening it. This should work too.

Comment: The device I am testing on is a FireTV - it doesn't have a "don't keep activities" in the developer options. 'Halt VM' from DDMS (which is what I assume you mean by force-close) just kills the app completely - you can't resume it.